# SQL developer exports the query resultset one by one when array fetch size is 50

Tags: oracle, export-to-excel, rdbms, oracle-sqldeveloper, database

I have two SQL queries with joins on multiple table and where clause and i wanted to export the resultset (~80k rows) to an excel sheet.

In my first query (has join for 8 table and an left outer join) exports the data in multiple of 50 rows in the progress bar, whereas second query (has join for 3 tables and no outer join) exports the data one by one.

What would be the reasons behind it?

Note that, the preference is set for `sql array fetch size as 50` in SQL developer.

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: It is most likely a fetch configuration for SQL Developer.

Comment: @JorgeCampos If yes, how come it can differ with two queries?

Comment: I woudn't know how to explain it, sorry.